# Is color mismatch normal when using Texture Paint Quick Edit?

Tags: materials, texture-painting

When I use *Quick Edit* to transfer a screen capture to PhotoShop, then edit the image, save it, and *Apply* it back in Blender, the image that is projected on is noticeably darker.  This causes lines to form all over the model where the borders of the projector are.  Here is an image.  Does anyone know how to work around this?

[image]

EDIT:  The image to the left is using *Perspective View* and the image to the right is using *Orthographic View*, There is a visible color bleed from the edges of other models that overlap for the projection.

I didn't add a .blend file since I restored Blender to the default settings before doing this.  Both images were made using 2048x2048 textures for both the *Bake* and for the *External Edit* settings.

[image]

Comment: When using Quick Edit feature, it's recommended that you turn on the Shadeless setting in Material tab, since it will affect the shade in the capture.

Comment: BTW, After r60783, it would be much easier to turn it on from Shading panel in the N panel of 3D view.

Comment: Well, using Shadeless did it for some of the errors that were occurring, thanks for the tip.  Unfortunately the problem of closer objects projecting through to what's behind is still happening.

Comment: I think that's because you didn't check Occlude option in the Project Paint menu before applying, which will avoid a "paint/project through" issue.

Comment: I had Occlude checked.  It's in by default,  I also tried turning Stencil on and I changed by sliders from their default values down to zero.  None of the settings above External Editing made any difference.

Comment: Would you mind to upload a simple .blend file to demostrate this issue? Seeing your settings may be helpful to tackle it.

Comment: I've updated the post with an additional image plus info.

Comment: I bet the three spheres are located in a single mesh, which is different from the spider case. If so, I'm afraid such issue is inevitable when using Quick Edit without any mask, because the screen capture can't save any Z data currently, and you are obviously editing an image with all pixels blended. To solve this, just use Mask tool on the header to limit the target area (the closer sphere, in this case) BEFORE applying it back. I'll make it as a more formal and detailed answer later if it can finally fix that.

Comment: Yes, you are correct that all the models are grouped as one mesh. Unfortunately, to work around this problem I've had to separate parts out to keep this issue from arising but it's not ideal since separating then reintegrating components into a single mesh can have adverse effects on modifiers. This is not the only problem that can turn up when this is done. Thanks for your help in this matter.

Comment: OK. So did you follow the suggestion of using mask instead of separating? Did it finally fix the problem?

Comment: ummm, no... I do not see any options for Masking like what are available in Sculpt, there is only Texture Mask but when I use this is has no masking effect.  Using Texture Mask, I can draw black areas on the object but this does not block painting the way it would in Sculpt. It just appears to be a way to draw black and white, painting over this "Mask" paints normally.  Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Hi, the Mask button can be found on the 3D View header when in Texture Paint mode, or press M to toggle on/off. FYI: http://www.pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=62765 Just toggle it, then select all the closer faces that you want to paint on, then paint, or apply back the Quick Edit result. It'll be more convenient for you to do selection easier in Edit mode, then switch back to Texture Paint mode. If you think this is the right direction to solve that, I'll try to make a demo video to show how to use it when necessary.

Comment: That is very useful to know, Thanks Leon.